# Add functions to models in Google App Engine DataStore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model

I am using Google App Engine with Python and DataStore. Is it possible to define a model, and attach functions directly to the model?

```
class ServiceState(db.model):
    service = db.StringProperty(required=True,
                                choices=('API', 'DB'))

    current = db.StringProperty(required=True,
                                choices=('UP', 'DOWN'))

    def change(self, new_state):
        # some other logic here
        self.current = new_state;
        self.put()
```

Then do something like:

```
  ss = models.ServiceStatus.gql("WHERE service = :1", "API")
  ss.change("DOWN")
```

**UPDATE**

Tried and getting:

```
 AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'change'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is possible.  I think I've seen examples with classmethods attached directly to the class -- I don't see any reason why you couldn't add regular methods as well (especially since the instances already have other instance methods like `key`).

Comment: Tried it, but getting `AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'change'`

Comment: that's because the `gql` method returns a `Query`-like object.  To actually get the instances of your model, you need to iterate over the query-like object... `for m in models.ServiceStatus.gql(...): m.change('DOWN')`